# Cannot get arrey out of "request-reply" module

Tags: flowground

I am trying to create a JSON array for our web app from a MSSQL database.
For this I use the following components:

`telekom/webhook:receive`

`telekom/mssql:selectAction`

```
select * from [dbo].[perso]
```

`telekom/request-reply:reply`

```
{
  "personalnr": personalnr,
  "firstname": firstname,
  "name": name,
  "email": email,
  "holidays": holidays
}
```

You can see in the dashboard that all 20 data records are read in and that they also arrive at `telekom/request-reply`. But as output I only get the first record back.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the connector retrieves a bunch of 20 rows from database.
Now there are two options a connector can transfer these rows to the next one.

- Option 1: transfer as a bunch as well; in this case you would see 1 processed event in dashboard. The following connector must be able to handle a bunch of rows himself.
- Option 2: every row will be transferred separately. In this case you would see 20 processed events. The following connector will get data from one row only and has to run 20 times.

As you can see, the MSSQL connector implements the second option. The following connector is the interesting one; he should run 20 times and in every pass he should process data from another row.